# Convert Item to string

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, mvvm, maui

It does not display the categories in the picker because in InitializeCategories I do ItemCategories.Add(category);, for it to display I have to do category.Text, however afterward it tells me that it can not convert a string to Item.

```
{

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsWithLocation { get; }

    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
    public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }
    public Command OnEditCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> DeleteItemCommand { get; }
    public ICommand SearchCommand { get; }
    private ObservableCollection<Item> filteredItems;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCategories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public ActivitieViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Browse";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        ItemsWithLocation = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

        ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);
        SearchCommand = new Command<string>(OnSearch);
        AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
        OnEditCommand = new Command(OnEditItem);
        DeleteItemCommand = new Command<Item>(OnDeleteItem);
        ItemCategories = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        InitializeCategories();
    }

    public Item SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedCategory; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedCategory != value)
            {
                _selectedCategory = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCategory));

                ReloadDataForCategory(_selectedCategory);
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public async Task InitializeCategories()
    {
        ItemCategories.Clear();
        var categories = await NewActivitie.GetItemCategoriesAsync();
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            ItemCategories.Add(category);
        }
    }

    public async Task ReloadDataForCategory(Item selectedCategory)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            if (selectedCategory != null)
            {
                Items.Clear();

                var items = await GetItemsAsync(true);
                var itemsForCategory = items.Where(category => category.CategoriesId.ToString() == selectedCategory.Id);

                List<Item> newItems = new List<Item>(); 

                foreach (var item in itemsForCategory)
                {
                    newItems.Add(item);
                }

                Items.Clear();
                foreach (var newItem in newItems)
                {
                    Items.Add(newItem);
                    FilterItems();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

  

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {

                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            Id = itemId,
                            Text = d.Name,
                            Description = d.Description,
                            Image = d.Images?.Blob ?? string.Empty,
                            UserId = d.UserId,
                            IsUpdated = loginUserId == d.UserId,
                            GroupId = d.Group_id,
                            Location = d.Location,
                            Start_date = d.Start_date,
                            End_date = d.End_date,
                            Start_time = d.Start_time,
                            End_time = d.End_time,
                            CategoriesId = d.CategoriesId,
                            ImagesId = d.ImagesId
                        };

                        if (!Items.Any(existingItem => existingItem.Id == itemId))
                        {
                            Items.Add(item);
                        }

                        if (d.Location != null && !ItemsWithLocation.Any(a => a.Id == itemId))
                        {
                            ItemsWithLocation.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return await Task.FromResult(Items);
    }
```

```
 public ActivitiePage(ActivitieViewModel activitieViewModel)

 {
     InitializeComponent();

     _activitieViewModel = activitieViewModel;
     BindingContext = _activitieViewModel;
     (BindingContext as ActivitieViewModel)?.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
 }

 private async void OnCategorySelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var selectedCategory = CategoryPicker.SelectedItem as Item;

     if (selectedCategory != null)
     {
         await _activitieViewModel.ReloadDataForCategory(selectedCategory);
     }
 }
```

```
 <Picker x:Name="CategoryPicker" Grid.Row="0" Title="Select Category" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCategories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" />
```

When I replace the ItemCategories in List it shows me the categories because afterwards I can do ItemCategories (category.text) however after that it no longer has access to the ID to identify

When I select a category it sorts well :

[image]

When I replace Item with List and ItemCategories(category) by ItemCategories(category.Text) it displays correctly, however sorting by category no longer works

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you clarify a bit more? Can you show what it looks like and what it should look like? Please also include only the relevant parts of the code. Anything that is irrelevant for the problem, shouldn't be presented here, because it only cludders the question.

Comment: I did everything you told me, I hope it's better

Comment: I think after ReloadDataForCategory you have to filter again because it reloads all the category items without filter.  Can you check if this solve the problem? Posting as a comment because i didn't have much time, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: I think it's roughly that but there are bugs: it doesn't show me the image and the title and also it shows me the same thing several times (I added image)

Comment: Afterwards I can successfully display the image with category.image but I receive: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Orbis.Mobile.Models.Item'

Comment: Which line causes that error?

Comment: I finally solved this problem thanks anyway

Comment: The last problem solved is that it does not display the categories in the picker because in InitializeCategories I do ItemCategories.Add(category);, for it to display I have to do category.Text, however afterward it tells me that it can not convert a string to Item.

Comment: Use ItemDisplayBinding to tell the picker which property to display

Answer (score 0):

If the object of your **Item** is, for example, this

```
public class Item
{
    public string TestText { get; set; }
}
```

Check this code

```
<Picker x:Name="CategoryPicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TestText}" Grid.Row="0" Title="Select Category" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCategories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"/>
```